# Using more than 2 displays on the M1 Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, apple-silicon

I have an M1 Pro MacBook Pro which can reportedly support up to 2 external displays. According to Apple:

> [The 14" MacBook Pro supports] up to two external displays with up to 6K resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors (M1 Pro)

Is it possible to drive three displays (at 4k60 each) using the M1 Pro MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1):

No.

According to the product page, the M1 Pro will max out at two external displays. You would need the M1 Max if you want more than 2 external displays.

From the [product page](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-14-and-16/specs/):

> ## Display Support
>
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
> at 1 billion colors and:
>
> - Up to two external displays with up to 6K resolution at 60Hz at over a
>   billion colors (**M1 Pro**) or
> - Up to three external displays with up to
>   6K resolution and one external display with up to 4K resolution at
>   60Hz at over a billion colors (**M1 Max**)